Prove that the median of a triangle bisects any segment parallel to its base without using similarity or Thales
Definition: A median of a triangle is a cevian that bisects the opposite side. [source]
Theorem: A median of a triangle bisects any segment parallel to the side bisected by this median and connecting the points on two other sides of a triangle.
The proof that uses triangle similarity is the following:


Let $ABC$ be a triangle with median $BM$ ($AM = MC$).
Let $D$ be the point on $AB$ and $E$ be the point on $BC$ such that $DE\parallel AC$.
Let the intersection point of $DE$ and $BM$ be $F$.
Triangles $ABM$ and $DBF$ are similar. Indeed, because $DE\parallel AC$, we have $\angle BDF = \angle BAM$ and $\angle BFD = \angle BMA$. Therefore, $AM\cdot BF = BM\cdot DF$, or $\frac{AM}{DF}=\frac{BM}{BF}$.
Apply the same reasoning to triangles $CBM$ and $EBF$ to conclude they are similar. Therefore, $CM\cdot BF = BM\cdot EF$, or $\frac{CM}{EF}=\frac{BM}{BF}$.
Therefore, we got that $\frac{AM}{DF}=\frac{BM}{BF}=\frac{CM}{EF}$.
As $AM=CM$, then we also have $DF=EF$ (the denominators of the equal fractions should be equal if their numerators are equal), which was to be proven.

I'm trying to find a proof for this fact that does not rely on triangle similarity. Ideally, that does not rely on Thales' theorem as well. Is there one? I suspect there is, through some sort of parallelograms, or something like that. It would really help me out with my research.

If $BD$ and $BA$ are commensurable, then you can show directly that $DF=FE$. Otherwise you can use some RAA argument.

@Intelligentipauca perhaps extending the triangle so that the segment in question will be the midline of this triangle will help too? Not too much of an idea so far.

You have to prove, some way, that $DF:AM=FE:MC$. If you don't want to use similarity you must revert to something more basic, at the cost of a much lengthier proof. Is there any good reason to do that?

@Intelligentipauca This will allow me to derive a proof for a much more significant theorem, that the intersection point of the diagonals of a trapezoid is collinear to the midpoints of two its bases, to a midpoint of its midline, and to the intersection point of two lines containing the lateral sides of that same trapezoid. It's very evident that it nails down to proving the statement in question with the same restrictions.


Use areas.
$$S_{\triangle{ABM}} = S_{\triangle{ACM}}$$
Also note that because $DE || BC$, the distance between those two is constant, and therefore $$S_{\triangle{DBM}} = S_{\triangle{ECM}}$$
and
$$S_{\triangle{ADM}} = S_{\triangle{ABM}} - S_{\triangle{DBM}} = S_{\triangle{ACM}} - S_{\triangle{ECM}} = S_{\triangle{AEM}}$$
which means perpendiculars $DI$ and $EJ$ drawn from $D$ and $E$ to $AM$ are of the same length.
Therefore
$$S_{\triangle{ADF}} = S_{\triangle{AEF}}$$
which means $|DF|$ must be equal to $|EF|$.

If no one would get anything else, you get the bonus! :)

Divide median $BM$ into an arbitrary number $n$ of equal parts ($n=8$ in the figure) and draw from the endpoints lines parallel to $AC$. These lines will intersect $AB$ and $BC$: from each intersection point draw a line parallel to $BM$ (see figure below). These lines will divide both $AM$ and $CM$ into $n$ parts.
It is easy to prove that all the little triangles thus created on the left of $BM$ (such as $BGH$ in the figure) are equal among them, as well as all the small parallelograms on the left of $BM$. It follows that $AM=nGH$.
Analogously, all all the little triangles on the right of $BM$ (such as $BIH$ in the figure) are equal among them, as well as all the small parallelograms on the right of $BM$. It follows that $AM=nIH$.
But $AM=BM$, hence $GH=IH=a$ and all the parallelograms are equal among them.
As $BF<BM$, there exists some integer number $m$ ($m=5$ in the figure) such that $mBH\le BF<(m+1)BH$, and consequently:
$$
ma\le DF<(m+1)a,\quad ma\le EF<(m+1)a.
$$
It follows that
$$
|EF-DF|<a={AM\over n}.
$$
As $n$ is arbitrary, we get $EF=DF$, otherwise we would have a contradiction. That completes the proof.

